# How do you include a distrbution of stencil components in an electron app

Tags: electron, content-security-policy, stenciljs

I am not really able to include a distribution of a stencil dist in a project. Due to electron being headless chrome, shouldn't it be possible to include it as a script?

I seem to have an error regarding the security policy

stencil versions:
1.12.2

They work good in standalone-html

```
index-64aa1cf6.js:2443 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-imoMl/F66ZbGZfn+J0jtlxdZvr/1ZBs+8ReasI4LBKQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

bootstrapLazy @ index-64aa1cf6.js:2443
index-64aa1cf6.js:2888 Refused to load the script 'blob:file:///f7aff0d4-a09c-464c-8344-451ac3a43fba' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Answer (score 1):

Electron is not headless chrome, it's based on Chromium.

Your error message is telling you that you have CSP (Content-Security Policy) enabled and therefore loading the script and inline style has been blocked.

You can either change the CSP rule so that it allows loading that script, or disable CSP (less secure).

Links:

- https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/security.md#6-define-a-content-security-policy
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

The issue might also just be that you're trying to include the script with a `blob:file://` protocol.

For the blocked inline-style you can either add a nonce or hash source to the directive (more secure), or use `'unsafe-inline'`.

Comment: Thank you i'll see what i can do with that. I think part of it may be, that stencil bundles use multiple JS files.